# File upload control with text box data for inserting in SQL server 2008 using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, file-upload, textbox

Presently, I am using file upload control for uploading files on SQL server through ASP.NET (using C#) successfully.  Now I am trying to make as page like this

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <p style="font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: 700; font-size: medium; color: #0000CC">
        Performance Feedback From Zonal Railways<p style="font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: 700; font-size: small; color: #990000">
        Performance feedback of :
        <asp:TextBox ID="equipment" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <p style="font-family: Tahoma; font-weight: 700; font-size: small; color: #990000">
        Uploaded by :
        <asp:TextBox ID="uploadedby" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
    <p class="style1">
        <strong>Letter Date : <asp:TextBox ID="Letterdt" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        </strong></p>
    <div>
        <span class="style1"><strong>Select File to Upload :</strong></span>
      <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
      <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="btnUpload_Click" Text="Upload File" />
      <br />
       <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" Font-Names = "Arial"></asp:Label>
    </div>
  </form>
    <p>
        <span class="style2"><strong><a href="../../elocosmainpage.htm">Back</a></strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span class="style3"><strong><a href="Default.aspx">Home</a></strong></span></p>
</body>
```

Please suggest any readymade example for meet the requirment or any code.

Comment: There is nothing called ready made. you have to initiate

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link where you can learn how to upload files to SQL Server Database

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-and-Download-files-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASPNet.aspx